# Uiimagepickercontroller autolayout issues only in Ipad 8.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

When I'm clicking `cell` in `tableView` ,it will open a `UIImagepickerController`. `Picker` got opened
but got this error in console .My UI get collapsed after dismissing `pickingController`.

Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
"",
    "",
    "
Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Note:This happen only in IPAD after 8.0 versions.But its works in ios7(iphone,ipad) and ios8(iphone) .Please help me to resolve it,Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

What it means is you have constraints set in your auto layout which cannot be satisfied.

For example:

Constraint 1: Height = 9:10 Parent.Height

Constraint 2: Height = 100

If both those constraints are set, and the parents height ends up being 90, then an issue will arise.

However you can avoid this by either removing a constraint OR setting a lower priority.

So if you wanted to keep constraint 2 in the example above, set its priority to 999 (instead of the 1000 default). This means it will try to make the height 100 so long as it doesn't override constraint 1.

To find the constraint causing issues, delete each constraint 1 at a time and run your code. When the message is gone you've found the constraint(s) causing the issue. Their priority can then be turned down (or removed entirely).

Comment: Thanks for your reply..As you said i removed constraint one by one.Now i'm not getting contraint error in console.My ui get collapsed because of cahnges,still when im closing a uiimagepickercontroller.My tableview is not showing.

Comment: I think you need to work on your Auto Layout fundamentals. Go through this tutorial. http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1

Comment: Thanks..I fixed the issue..Just adding UIModalPresentationCustom for UimagePickercontroller..